# continuity of DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE:
$$y'+y=g(t), \quad y(0)=0,$$ where $g(t)=2$ when $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $g(t)=0$, homogeneous, when $t>1$.  So I've shown that $$y(t)=2(1-e^{-t})$$ and was wondering what is the significance of having a continuous solution?

Comment: That seems to be a solution for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, but not when $t > 1$....

Comment: The question is vague. But since $g$ isn't continuous and assuming to solve this you actually solved two differential equations (one for each piecewise component of $g$) and got the same solution in $[0,+\infty[$, there is no reason to expect that the given solution will be continuous in this interval.

Comment: they say Newton calculated logarithms to 20 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the non-homogeneous part of the equation, can be written as: 
$$g(t) = 2 \,(1- H(t-1)),$$ where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function. This been said, you can proceed taking Laplace's transform on both sides of the equation or, solving by parts on each time interval. If you proceed with Laplace's help, you will have:

$$(s + 1 ) Y(s) =  2 \left(\frac{1}{s} - \frac{e^{-s}}{s}  \right),  $$ where $Y( s ) = \mathcal{L}_s [y(t)]$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: perhaps there is a way to do this with a complex integral? $$y(t) = \mathcal{L}_s^-1 [Y(s)]$$

Comment: Hi @user131326! There's no need of computing the inverse Laplace transform with complex integrals. Actually, you will end up with a series of 'easy'(tabulated) terms to inverse-Laplace transform separately.

Comment: Oh but we must do this in the complex plane it is more beautiful=)